# Spring - How to prevent response from converting into newline characters?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring

On my front end I have a `jQuery` ajax GET request to /reports/1

In my controller I have wired this request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/1", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getReport(){...};
```

I'm trying to return a string containing a tab character. Looking at the return value of this function the tab character is still being displayed as \t (ex. string is "test\tstring"). However, when I look at the response received in chrome the response is already returning the \t converted into an actual tab, and `JSON` is giving me a parse error.

I have also tried setting `produces = javascript/text` in my request mapping.

How do I prevent the tab character from converting into actual tabs before I try to parse the `JSON`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So im still not sure exactly where the character conversion is happening (assuming somewhere in spring), but I was able to temporarily fix this by replacing \t characters in my string with \t characters.